# SQL Server 2016 Not Connecting to Local Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016

So I've been stuck on this issue for a while, but basically my ASP.NET MVC project is now unable to load because for some reason my local database is unreachable.

I initially thought this was an issue in my code because when I tried to refresh the webpage I was working on, it just got stuck on "connecting to localhost". But then when I entered SQL Server Management Studio and tried to connect to the instance of SQL Server 2016 I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to DESKTOP-5QC21BI\SQLSERVER2016.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a
 connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. 
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to 
allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error 
Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=-1&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

I looked around for some answers as to why this would randomly occur. One second, the site was working great and all of the sudden the db wont connect. However I am just honestly too unfamiliar with the issue to be able to find a good fix. Is there anything I can do to resolve this connection? I can't seem to understand why there would be a network related error for a local database.

Comment: This could happen if the SQL Server Database Engine service is down for some reason. You said you could not connect from the Management Studio either. So need to be that when you cannot connect at that time the service is down or not.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to reset the Data Base engine? I closed Management Studio and even reset my computer and the issue persisted, however when I got on this morning it had been resolved. Again, this is a local database, so I'm confused as to how the service went down.